# How to align icon to the center in an <i> tag of fixed height

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I tried adding some `padding-top`, but is there a way to automate this? I couldn't find any similar questions.

```css
i{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
```

Comment: but why you don't consider the icon as the `i` element and use another wrapper ? there is no logic doing so

Comment: @TemaniAfif that's what I'd done before, aligned it inside a parent div tag, but I thought there might be an easier way.

Comment: it's about *easier* way ... the `i` is the icon element, why doing so and then trying to align it's pseudo element ... your don't have to mess up with the i element, you will simply create a lot issue

Comment: It's for a really specific scenario. While I won't go into all the details, it's a vuejs component with a complicated structure, and a container element would've proved to be more challenging.

Comment: so the easiest way here without the complication i see below is to set `line-height` the same as height

Comment: Yeah, either that or the pseudo element. Having said that, why has this been marked as duplicate? The three questions attached don't address the same issue.

Comment: simply because vertical-alignment is a common issue ... and ALL the question address the issue, because the content of a pseudo element is a text so here you want to "vertical-align a text within a container" .. and you will find the same answer below but better explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this helps you out. Kindly check the below snippet.

```css
i{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

i:before {
position: relative;
top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
```

Comment: i guess position:absolute is more correct ... it work here because you have no padding, but add padding to the i and you will see

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
i {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    width: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use table cell, and vertical align middle the advantage of using this is that old browser support table-cell property... other solution would be using flexbox..

```css
i{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
i.fa {
display:table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to add height. you can apply following css:

```
i{
  background: red;
  padding:8px;
}
```

And if you want keep height there than you can use following:

```
i{
     background: red;
     height:100px;
     display: table-cell !important;
     vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change your CSS like below:

```css
i{
  background: red;
  height: 100px;
}
i:before{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 40px 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.10/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<i class="fa fa-link"></i>
```